# AudioKit metronome synced with time-pitched audio loops

Tags: audiokit

I'm making an app that plays synced audio loops with a metronome. For example, I might have 3 files like this:

- `bass_60bpm.m4a`
- `drums_60bpm.m4a`
- `guitar_60bpm.m4a`

And a metronome sound `tick.m4a`, which I play with `AKSamplerMetronome`.

I need to play them back at arbitrary tempos, so I use `AKTimePitcher` on the `AKAudioFile`s (so playing at 90bpm, I'd play `bass_60bpm.m4a` at 1.5x).

This almost works, but after 3-5 loops, the metronome gets out of sync with the audio loops. I think I understand why that happens (audio_sample_length * floating_point_number is not equivalent to AKSamplerMetronome's tempo calculations), but I don't know how to fix it.

What I suspect I need to do is manually reimplement some or all of `AKSamplerMetronome`, but play the metronome ticks based on `AKTimePitcher`'s output, but I can't piece together enough info from the API, docs, and examples to make it happen.

Comment: How are you playing the files? Can you map out the unit connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate approach might be to use AKSequencer instead of AKSamplerMetronome. The midi output of the sequencer's track could be sent to an AKCallbackInstrument, and the sequencer's events could get the callback function to trigger both the time-stretched sample and the metronome ticks (and you could also trigger synchronized UI events from there as a bonus). This would guarantee that they stay in sync.

Apple's MusicSequence, which is what AKSequencer uses under the hood, is a little flakey with its timing immediately after you call play, but it's pretty solid after that. If you start the sequencer just before its looping point (i.e., if you have a 1 bar loop, start it one sixteenth note before the end of the first bar) then you can get passed that flakiness before the actual loop starts.

Comment: This worked well after much fiddling. I set up a sequencer, added a track with MIDI output to `AKCallbackInstrument`, added MIDI events for metronome clicks, and one MIDI event for "start time-pitched audio players." I'll try to remember to post sample code later.